# Specified cast is not valid with field int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, int

I keep getting the "Specified cast is not valid" error on my code in the ID column. I tried using

```
data.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
```

to let it know that the ID is an int. I am getting the data from a local .xls file.

here's my code:

```
  foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()

                    {
                        TrackID = p.Field<int>("ID"),

                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
                        Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
                    };

                    data.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

                    daa.Add(top);
                }
```

here's my class:

```
 public class TopPlayed
{
    public int TrackID { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string Times { get; set; }
}
```

cheers in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `double` instead.  Excel exposes data as either strings or doubles.

```
TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()

{
    TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("ID")),

    TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
    ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
    Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is checking our type (with *Watch* window for example):

```
row.Table.Columns["id"].DataType
```

What print (in my case): `{Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}`, then change your code to proper type:

```
TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()    
{
    TrackID = p.Field<Int64>("ID"),
    TrackName = p.Field<string>("Track Name"),
    ArtistName = p.Field<string>("Artist Name"),
    Times = p.Field<double>("NoOfPlays").ToString()
};

public class TopPlayed
{
    public Int64 TrackID { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string Times { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a query inside a query, the best way that worked is to submit a simple String
and then to convert it to int32 ex.:

**instead of using**

> p.Field("ID")

**do it**

> row["ID"]